# Asp.net Client Side Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

here is my code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
  <div id="altForm" role="form">
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                          <label>اسماء الخدمات</label>   
                         <div style='overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 200px;'>                              
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="drpRequestCategories" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control chosen_list" runat="server" Width="100%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpRequestCategories_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                              </asp:DropDownList>
                             </div>
                                <br />
                        </div>
              </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

     <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="بحث" class="submit btn btn-blue Save" OnClick="btnSearch_OnClick"/>
</asp:Content>
```

I fill this dropdownlist by client side dynamically 
I read the answers that update panel will solve the problem but it still founded please help

I fill the dropdownlist by this Function

```
   function filldropdownlistcategory(res) {             
        var select = document.getElementById('<%= drpRequestCategories.ClientID %>');
        var test = $.parseJSON(res.d);
        $('#<%= drpRequestCategories.ClientID %>').empty();
        $(test).each(function () {               
            var option = $('<option />');
            option.attr('value', this.ServiceID).text(this.ServiceName);
            $('#<%= drpRequestCategories.ClientID %>').append(option);
        });        
    }
```

the error is

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: @fubo updated my question

Comment: as it says, put a `%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>` on your page